# Is there any way of expression to substitute "to be called into question"?

Tags: phrase-request, legalese

I wish to replace "to be called into question" with "raise doubt over" or "cast doubt on" in the sentence below:

> Based on the judgment on Case No. xxxx (X v. Y), would the independence of such authorities be called into question?

I don't know how to make it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on the judgment on Case No. xxxx (X v. Y), would the independence of such authorities be called into question?

There are two main components to the sentence:

- *the judgment on Case No. xxxx (X v. Y)*
- *the independence of such authorities*

The sentence structure looks like this:

> Based on X, would Y ***be called into question***?

---

Rephrasing it to use the other phrase results in this revised structure:

> Would X ***cast doubt on*** Y?

Therefore, what you want is this:

> Would *the judgment on Case No. xxxx (X v. Y)* ***cast doubt on*** *the independence of such authorities*?

---

Note that, in the revised structure, you can simply replace *cast doubt on* with *raise doubt over*.